# WordPress site under localhost is disassociated with the code

Tags: localhost, configuration, eclipse

I have put the folder `wordpress` under `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, and `localhost/wordpress/` in a browser shows well the site.

However, I changed `Just another WordPress site` to `Just another WordPress site hahaha`, the site on the right side cannot reflect this change.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: First, you shouldn't be making any changes in WordPress core files. They will get overwritten whenever you update. Second, that text is changed in your WordPress admin section, under Settings->General->Tagline

Comment: I see... I can edit this tagline in the WordPress Dashboard tool. But it is odd that I could not change it in the code, no? Also, what am I supposed to change in WordPress files? only themes?

Comment: No it is not odd. The tagline is retrieved from the database, not from code. The line you changed is in a function that populates the database with the default options.